# Retrieving the last record not the first from in group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like

```
Country_d  Country      Code Year Month Index 
    2       Germany     DEU  2020   9   
    2       Germany     DEU  2020   10  
    2       Germany     DEU  2020   11   58
    2       Germany     DEU  2020   12   72
    2       Germany     DEU  2021   1    61
    2       Germany     DEU  2021   2    39
    2       Germany     DEU  2021   3    38
    2       Germany     DEU  2021   4
```

My query is like this

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT d.year, d.month, d.country_id as value
    FROM `general` d
    INNER JOIN units c ON c.id = d.country_id
    WHERE d.country_id IN (185) 
    ORDER BY c.unit_en, d.year DESC, d.month DESC ) `data`
GROUP BY country_id
```

The query returns

```
Country   Code    Year   Month   Index
======================================
Germany   DEU     2020     11      58
```

What must return is the latest updated month and index. In this case must return

```
Country   Code    Year   Month   Index
======================================
Germany   DEU     2021     3      38
```

because this is the latest updated month with Index

I have tried to add `MAX()` for the `d.year` and `d.month` like `SELECT MAX(d.year), MAX(d.month), d.country_id as value` but then for the month return month 4 which doesn't have index.

When I remove `GROUP BY country_id` it shows all data too..

Any suggestions how can I change the query?

Comment: Have you tried turning the two `DESC` into `ASC`?

Comment: Yes, nothing is changing.

Comment: What's `c.unit_en`? Do you still need to sort by that?

Comment: Can your MySql version use [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)?

Comment: `c.unit_en` are the titles and no, seems not need for sorting. Removed it from the query and still show the first instead of the last populated row.

Comment: MySQL Version is `10.3.32-MariaDB-log`

Comment: Looks like a MariaDB version to me.

Comment: The query is invalid. MySQL let's this slip unnoticed when in cheat mode (i.e. the user forgot to `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` in order to get a reliable system). You say your DBMS returns rows rather than throwing an exception. So, obviously MariaDB has the same issue. You cannot `select *` when you group by country and your data set contains more than one row per country. Understand this. Make sure you work in the proper mode in order to get informed of invalid queries. (What is probably happening is that Maria DB silently applies `ANY_VALUE` to all your columns, which is undesired)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, that's really interesting. Didn't knew about this too..Will have a look on this. Thanks!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I'm really trying to understand this but having some hard times on it. Can you give me some simple example why is the problem if the group by country is a problem if it is has more than one rows?

Comment: If we have two rows for country_id 185 and we `select * from mytable where country_id = 185 group by country`, then which row's values shall be taken? Which year for example? The lesser one? the greater one? the average? When you aggregate, you must state this, e.g. `select country_id, max(year), avg(month), ...`. Make sure to always `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` so the DBMS checks whether your query is valid. Without that mode, MariaDB allows the invalid `select *`, but converts it silently into `select country_id, any_value(year), any_value(month)`, i.e. values picked arbitrarily.

Comment: Another point is a subquery with an `ORDER BY` clause. A (sub)query result is a table and tables are unordered data sets. This means the `ORDER BY` clause is completely superfluous, as the DBMS is free to ignore it. Some DBMS even throw a syntax error to show you that you are applying a nonsensical clause. I consider it a great feature, if a DBMS helps you thus writing proper queries.

Comment: It's more clear now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER to calculate a sequencial number per country.
Then the 1st is what you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT d.year, d.month, d.country_id
    , c.unit_en
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.country_id ORDER BY d.year DESC, d.month DESC) AS rn
    FROM `general` d
    INNER JOIN units c ON c.id = d.country_id
    WHERE d.country_id IN (185)
    AND d.Index IS NOT NULL
) `data`
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Look pretty good. l didn't used ROW_NUMBER() before. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonWung  Thanks. Then I suggest you have a glance at [this page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/). Just to be aware that there's more cool stuff like that.